# Showing php page as an image

Tags: php

is that possible to show whole php page as an image file like png or jpg ?

for example,

```
<img src="details.php?id=44">
```

just like a screenshot of the page.

Thx

Comment: You might be interested in http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=screenshot+website+php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  <?
  // details.php file
  // {
  // do stuff to create your image and store in $my_image
  // }
  header("Content-type: image/jpg");
  echo $my_image;
  ?>
```

1) output the mime type in the header.

2) echo your binary data

easy!

Comment: uhh.. he wants a screenshot of the HTML output of the PHP script.

Comment: so what would a screenshot of a page that makes a screenshot look like? recursion??

Answer (score 0):

Not in the way you're thinking. You can use the PHP ImageMagick library or the PHP GD Library to generate an image dynamically and output it, but in order to get screenshots of a page you'll really need an outside service.

Comment: Taking a screenshot of the page will be impossible with ImageMagick. If you just want to display stuff with ImageMagick (not a rendered HTML/CSS page), take a look at http://us.php.net/manual/en/class.imagick.php

Answer (score 0):

it depends on what you want to show. if its html/js/css, it varies across browsers.

If its unicode text to be displayed as images, you can use GD library for the purpose

Answer (score 0):

I think you are talking about taking screenshots of a url or webpage. You can you freely available like:
http://www.shrinktheweb.com/
http://picoshot.com/
There are many such freely available services. If you want to host such service on your own server. You will need to create a software which can open your browser and take screenshot of the url. Ther are some softwares available as well. I hope it helps.